# Modifications of PineScript indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

Hope you are doing well.

I'm working on a Pine Script indicator and I've successfully implemented the main logic, but I'm facing challenges with further enhancements. Here is the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='y.z test ind', shorttitle='y.z test ind', overlay=true)

// Declare the variables for the highest and lowest points of the structure
var float bosHigh = na
var float bosLow = na

// Initialize bosHigh and bosLow values
if na(bosHigh)
    bosHigh := high
if na(bosLow)
    bosLow := low

// Declare variables to track bearish and bullish breaks and their counts
var bool bearishBreak = false
var bool bullishBreak = false
var int bearishBreakCount = 0
var int bullishBreakCount = 0

// Variable to track whether a new low/high is formed after a break
var bool newLowFormed = false
var bool newHighFormed = false

// Function to plot the break count labels
f_plotBreakCount(_breakCount, _price, _isBullish) =>
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=_price, text=str.tostring(_breakCount), style=label.style_label_down, color=_isBullish ? color.red : color.green, yloc=_isBullish ? yloc.abovebar : yloc.belowbar, textcolor=color.white)

// Logic for detecting breaks and forming new highs/lows
if close > bosHigh
    bosHigh := high
    bosLow := low
    bearishBreak := true
    bullishBreak := false
    bullishBreakCount := 0
    bearishBreakCount += 1
    newLowFormed := false
    int i = 1
    bool waveFound = true
    while waveFound and i < 2000
        if close[i] < open[i]
            if close[i] < low[i+1]
                waveFound := false
                newLowFormed := true
        if low[i] < bosLow
            bosLow := low[i]
        i += 1
    if newLowFormed
        f_plotBreakCount(bearishBreakCount, bosLow, false)

if close < bosLow
    bosLow := low
    bosHigh := high
    bearishBreak := false
    bullishBreak := true
    bearishBreakCount := 0
    bullishBreakCount += 1
    newHighFormed := false
    int i = 1
    bool waveFound = true
    while waveFound and i < 2000
        if close[i] > open[i]
            if close[i] > high[i+1]
                waveFound := false
                newHighFormed := true
        if high[i] > bosHigh
            bosHigh := high[i]
        i += 1
    if newHighFormed
        f_plotBreakCount(bullishBreakCount, bosHigh, true)

// Plot the high and low of the structure
plot(title='BosHigh', series=bosHigh, color=color.rgb(234, 25, 14), linewidth=1, offset=0, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(title='BosLow', series=bosLow, color=color.rgb(234, 25, 14), linewidth=1, offset=0, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Currently, the arrows are displayed at any breaks, but I want to refine this. I aim to display arrows only when a new low is formed after a bullish break or a new high is formed after a bearish break. If the new low or high remains the same after the break, arrows shouldn't be displayed.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wasSW.png)

Can someone help me to understand how to implements this ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I not know how it works (once I asked - I implemented). I already added the counting the breaks :)
But the labelling is still worked wrong. 
Currently, the arrows are still displayed at any breaks, but I want to refine this. I would see arrows **only when a new low is formed after a bullish break** or **a new high is formed after a bearish break**. 
If the new low or high remains the same after the break, arrows shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: You should post question details in the actual question and not in a comment. You should [edit] your question and add the details that you posted in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I gave my Best. Pls confirm if the below code is correct or not

```
//@version=5
// indicator(title='y.z test ind', shorttitle='y.z test ind', overlay=true)

// Declare the variables for the highest and lowest points of the structure
var float bosHigh = na
var float bosLow = na

// Initialize bosHigh and bosLow values
if na(bosHigh)
    bosHigh := high
if na(bosLow)
    bosLow := low

// Declare variables to track bearish and bullish breaks and their counts
var bool bearishBreak = false
var bool bullishBreak = false
var int bearishBreakCount = 0
var int bullishBreakCount = 0

// Variable to track whether a new low/high is formed after a break
var bool newLowFormed = false
var bool newHighFormed = false
// Function to plot the break count labels
f_plotBreakCount(_breakCount, _price, _isBullish) =>
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=_price, text=str.tostring(_breakCount), style=label.style_label_down, color=_isBullish ? color.red : color.green, yloc=_isBullish ? yloc.abovebar : yloc.belowbar, textcolor=color.white)

// Logic for detecting breaks and forming new highs/lows
if close > bosHigh
    bosHigh := high
    bosLow := low
    bearishBreak := true
    bullishBreak := false
    bullishBreakCount := 0
    bearishBreakCount += 1
    newLowFormed := false
    int i = 1
    bool waveFound = true
    while waveFound and i < 2000
        if close[i] < open[i]
            if close[i] < low[i+1]
                waveFound := false
                newLowFormed := true
        if low[i] < bosLow
            bosLow := low[i]
        i += 1
    if newLowFormed and (newHighFormed[1]==true)
        f_plotBreakCount(bearishBreakCount, bosLow, false)

if close < bosLow
    bosLow := low
    bosHigh := high
    bearishBreak := false
    bullishBreak := true
    bearishBreakCount := 0
    bullishBreakCount += 1
    newHighFormed := false
    int i = 1
    bool waveFound = true
    while waveFound and i < 2000
        if close[i] > open[i]
            if close[i] > high[i+1]
                waveFound := false
                newHighFormed := true
        if high[i] > bosHigh
            bosHigh := high[i]
        i += 1
    if newHighFormed and (newLowFormed[1]==true)
        f_plotBreakCount(bullishBreakCount, bosHigh, true)
    

// Plot the high and low of the structure
plot(title='BosHigh', series=bosHigh, color=color.rgb(234, 25, 14), linewidth=1, offset=0, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(title='BosLow', series=bosLow, color=color.rgb(234, 25, 14), linewidth=1, offset=0, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed. The arrows/numbers are still displayed at any breaks :(

Comment: Are you expecting only number 1 label?

Comment: No, not only label with number 1. I expect that the labels (with correspond numbers, counting functionality is already implemented) will be displayed at any break only **when a new low is formed after a bullish break** (bullish scenario) or at any break only **when a new high is formed after a bearish break** (bearish scenario). I tried to draw which break I expect to display+count and which not expect to display on the image above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! maybe you have some other idea how we can solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='y.z test ind', shorttitle='y.z test ind', overlay=true)
var float bosHigh = na
var float bosLow = na

// Initialize bosHigh and bosLow values
if na(bosHigh)
    bosHigh := high
if na(bosLow)
    bosLow := low

// Declare variables to track bearish and bullish breaks and their counts
var bool bearishBreak = false
var bool bullishBreak = false
var int bearishBreakCount = 0
var int bullishBreakCount = 0

// Variable to track whether a new low/high is formed after a break
var bool newLowFormed = false
var bool newHighFormed = false
var string signal = na
// Function to plot the break count labels
f_plotBreakCount(_breakCount, _price, _isBullish) =>
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=_price, text=str.tostring(_breakCount),style=label.style_label_down, color=_isBullish ? color.red : color.green, yloc=_isBullish ? yloc.abovebar : yloc.belowbar, textcolor=color.white)

// Logic for detecting breaks and forming new highs/lows
if close > bosHigh
    bosHigh := high
    bosLow := low
    bearishBreak := true
    bullishBreak := false
    bullishBreakCount := 0
    bearishBreakCount += 1
    newLowFormed := false
    int i = 1
    bool waveFound = true
    while waveFound and i < 2000
        if close[i] < open[i]
            if close[i] < low[i+1]
                waveFound := false
                newLowFormed := true
        if low[i] < bosLow
            bosLow := low[i]
        i += 1
    if newLowFormed and not (signal[1]=="low")
        f_plotBreakCount(bearishBreakCount, bosLow, false)
        signal:="low"

if close < bosLow
    bosLow := low
    bosHigh := high
    bearishBreak := false
    bullishBreak := true
    bearishBreakCount := 0
    bullishBreakCount += 1
    newHighFormed := false
    int i = 1
    bool waveFound = true
    while waveFound and i < 2000
        if close[i] > open[i]
            if close[i] > high[i+1]
                waveFound := false
                newHighFormed := true
        if high[i] > bosHigh
            bosHigh := high[i]
        i += 1
    if newHighFormed and not (signal[1]=="high")
        f_plotBreakCount(bullishBreakCount, bosHigh, true)
        signal:="high"

// Plot the high and low of the structure
plot(title='BosHigh', series=bosHigh, color=color.rgb(234, 25, 14),linewidth=1, offset=0, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(title='BosLow', series=bosLow, color=color.rgb(234, 25, 14),linewidth=1, offset=0, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

This is how it is being displayed now. Please confirm, if this is the expected result
https://www.tradingview.com/x/eJ4rTeao/

Comment: no, not every bos is mapped